# jquery confused with multiple DropDownLists in same class name

Tags: jquery, vb.net, razor, model-view-controller

I have more than one DropDownListFor generated in a partial view as the following:

In loop:

```
 @Html.Action("listUnpairedPermissions", item)
```

The partial view code:

```
<div>
    @If CType(Model, IEnumerable(Of UserModel.Permission)).Count > 0 Then
    @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(r) CType(Model, IEnumerable(Of UserModel.Permission)).LastOrDefault.permission_ID, New SelectList(Model, "permission_Id", "permission_description"), "--Select--", New With {.Class = "pID"})
        Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.SingleOrDefault.permission_ID)


    Else
    @<p>This Role has all permissions</p>

    End If
</div>
```

My jquery code:

```
    $('.AddPermission2Role').each(function (index) {
        $(this).on("click", function () {
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var _role_id = tr.find('.roleIdClass').attr('roleIdTD');

            var _permission_id = $('.pID').val();
            var _parameters = { id: _role_id, permissionId: _permission_id };
            $('.pID').change();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/AdminUsers/AddPermission2Role",
                type: "GET",
                data: _parameters,
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    $('#roleToPermTable').html(data);
                }


            });
        });
    });
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<div>
<select class="pID" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field permission_ID must be a number." data-val-required="The permission_ID field is required." id="permission_ID" name="permission_ID"><option value="">--Select--</option>
<option value="0">admin-create</option>
<option value="1009">test_Perm</option>
</select></div>
<input type="button" class="AddPermission2Role" value="Add Permission">

... 
<div>
<select class="pID" id="permission_ID" name="permission_ID"><option value="">--Select--</option>
<option value="3">AdminUsers-RoleIndex</option>
<option value="4">AdminUsers-RoleManage</option>
<option value="5">AdminUsers-AddRoleToUser</option>
<option value="6">AdminUsers-DeleteUserRoleReturnPartialView</option>
<option value="7">AdminUsers-PermissionIndex</option>
<option value="8">AdminUsers-addPermission</option>
<option value="41">AdminUsers-UsersRoleIndex</option>
<option value="1008">AdminUsers-addRole</option>
<option value="1009">test_Perm</option>
<option value="1010">AdminUsers-listUnpairedPermissions</option>
<option value="1011">AdminUsers-AddPermission2Role</option>
<option value="1012">Adminusers-DeletePermissionFromRole</option>
</select>
</div>
<input type="button" class="AddPermission2Role" value="Add Permission">
```

Now when I select a value from the second list, my jquery doesn't pick the selected value. However, if I select from the first list and hit the button for the second list, it will get the value correctly!

My question is that How I can get a unique dropdown list each has its own submission button? 
In another word, how can my jquerycode  be able to differentiate between the lists if they have the same class name accordingly to their buttons?

Comment: why don't you use id instead?

Comment: I did and it is the same . when I click the second button for the second list, it just does not pick the selected value. @un-lucky

Comment: show us the rendered html too

Comment: @AnoopJoshi Post updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything contains the same id, so that will never work either.

What I typically do is provide my objects with a NonMapped HtmlId property that contains the object.typename + object.id concatenated, e.g. 'persmissionlist1', 'permissionlist2', and then I use this in my partial views as the id whenever I need a unique one specific to this one.

Comment: I thought that what I was doing! can you elaborate on that more please?

Comment: If you look at the id for the selects you quoted, it is permission_ID for both of them. But you would want them to be different, eg. permission1 and permission2

Comment: I managed to do so but still I'm having the same issue! Do I need to have different IDs for buttons as well? @Arwin

Comment: Yes - and  basically as a guideline, ids should be unique.